# I can not get account information with google login

Tags: android, google-signin

My application needs to sign in through Google. I opened the tutorial from firebase (but first you need to configure Google itself) Did as it was written in the instructions. However, it does not work. And why that result.isSuccess () is always false. Accordingly, I can not get account information.

LogCat:

```
08-04 08:32:28.128 1948 1948 D     AutoManageHelper                             starting AutoManage for client 0 false false
08-04 08:32:28.136 1948 1948 D     AutoManageHelper                             onStart true {0=com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqm$zza@efb56ec}
08-04 08:32:28.296 1948 1974 E     GED                                          Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)
08-04 08:32:35.293 1948 1948 D     Tag                                          handleSignInResult:false
```

Code:

```
import android.content.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.support.v7.app.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View.*;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.*;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.*;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.*;
import android.util.*;
import android.support.v4.app.*;
import com.google.android.gms.common.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class GoogleSigInActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
{

    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
    private String TAG = "Tag";
    TextView mStatusTextView;
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult p1)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gogle_sign_in);
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).
            requestEmail().
            build();

        // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
        // options specified by gso.

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).
            enableAutoManage(this, this).
            addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso).
            build();

        mStatusTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.activitygoglesigninTextView1);

        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View p1)
                {
                    switch (p1.getId())
                    {
                        case R.id.sign_in_button :
                            signIn(); 
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    private void signIn()
    {

        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN)
        {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result)
    {

        Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());


        if (result.isSuccess())
        {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            mStatusTextView.setText("work " + acct.getDisplayName());
        }
        else
        {
            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
            mStatusTextView.setText("not work");
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first check if you have enabled the "Google Play Game Services" API from your [API console](https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/apiui/apis/library). This enables your app to use the auth services. 
For me, the google sign in only worked for the signed APKs of my application, could not make it work in debug build.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it)